# PHP HttpRequest to create a web page - how to handle long response times?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I am currently using javascript and XMLHttpRequest on a static html page to create a view of a record in Zotero. This works nicely except for one thing: The page html title.

I can of course also change the `<title>...</title>` tag, but if someone wants to post the view to for example facebook the static title on the web page will be shown there.

I can't think of any way to fix this with just a static page with javascript. I believe I need a dynamically created page from a server that does something similar to XMLHttpRequest.

For PHP there is HTTPRequest. Now to the problem. In the javascript version I can use asynchronous calls. With PHP I think I need synchronous calls. Is that something to worry about?

Is there perhaps some other way to handle this that I am not aware of?

UPDATE: It looks like those trying to answer are not at all familiar with Zotero. I should have been more clear. Zotero is a reference db located at http://zotero.org/. It has an API that can be used through XMLHttpRequest (which is what I said above).

Now I can not use that in my scenario which I described above. So I want to call the Zotero server from my server instead. (Through PHP or something else.)

(If you are not familiar with the concepts it might be hard to understand and answer the question. Of course.)

UPDATE 2: For those interested in how Facebook scraps an URL you post there, please test here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

As you can see by testing there no javascript is run.

Comment: The title doesn't match the question.

Comment: Thanks @Popnoodles, but how do you mean? I mean that with the javascript version I did not have to worry about long response times from the Zotero server since the calls in javascript are async. I do not know to handle long response times in the PHP case.

Comment: Is it how to handle long response times or how to change the document title?

Comment: @Popnoodles I see ;-). It is actually entirely about long response times. But practically I need to change the title (in this particular case).

Comment: Ok, the question is missing a required degree of clarity.

Comment: Yes, if you say so, @Popnoodles. Suggestions for clarifications are welcome.

Comment: So I have added some more technical details. Please do not answer if you do not understand them!

Comment: *"Is that something to worry about?"* Nope. The API (server) just sees an incoming HTTP request, it doesn't know and care how the client is performing this request.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, but the "client" for the call to the Zotero sever is my web server in this case. Isn't there any problem with that? I mean my server will be hanging there until the Zotero server responds. Does that block something else? (I really have not idea!)

Comment: Well, of course it's blocking. What problem do you think might there be? Why don't you just try it and see if there is any problem?

Comment: @FelixKling Eh, yes, it is blocking ;-) -- I thought there might be some performance problem on my server then. But I guess I am just a bit too paranoid there. I will test. (And maybe I could use redirect instead - if fb URL scrapping handles that.)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, im not sure if i understand what you are trying to ask, are you just wanting to change the pages title?

Why not use javascript?

```
document.title = newTitle
```

Comment: +1 for answering what seems to be the actual question and completely ignoring the title that seems to be about something else.

Comment: I wasn't to sure what on earth i was trying to answer for him?  His title and text are completely different O_o

Comment: Thanks NZ Mikey. Yes, I can do that - and I said so in the question. The problem is that the javascript is not run when someone is posting the page to for example facebook. (The title should reflect the record fetched from the Zotero server.)

Comment: Sorry, your question is quite confusing.  Basically you are wanting a dynamically created page to post on facebook, which will have the dynamically created pages title?

Comment: Yes. But the title is fetched from another server (the Zotero server).

Answer (score 1):

Facebook expects the title (or opengraph :title tags) to be present when it fetches the page. It won't execyte any JavaScript for you to fill in the blanks.

A cool workaround would be to detect the Facebook scraper with PHP by parsing the User Agent string, and serving a version of the page with the information already filled in by PHP instead of JavaScript.

As far as I know, the Facebook scraper uses this header for User Agent: `"facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"`

You can check to see if part of that string is present in the header and load the page accordingly.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'facebookexternalhit') !== false)
{
    //synchronously load the title and opengraph tags here.
}
else
{
    //load the page normally
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that is a cool idea. But I guess people will be posting to other sites than fb too. Is there perhaps some more generic way to detect an og-scrapper (or any other scrapper)?